# Determining Python package location prior to import

Tags: python, import, path

I want to get the location of a package **before** importing it.  Basically I'd like to do

```
import pkg
pkg_path = pkg.__file__
```

but without having to `import pkg`.  Right now I'm doing:

```
target = "pkg"
target_path = None
for p in sys.path:
    search_path = "%s/%s" % (p, target)
    if os.path.exists(search_path):
        target_path = search_path
```

but there are several scenarios where this won't work (`target` doesn't contain `__init__.py`, `target` is inside a compressed EGG file).

Is there any better way to get `target_path`?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is [`imp.find_module()`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.find_module):

```
target_path = imp.find_module(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[__import__()][1]` as follow:

```
target_path = __import__('pkg').__file__
```

`__import__()` is used by `import` and one of its uses is when the module name is only known at runtime.